# googleapis npm module "analytics is not a function"

Tags: node.js

I am trying integrate google analytics API "server to server"  in Node.js.
I am following this [Server-to-server authorization for Google Analytics API with Node.js](http://www.bentedder.com/server-to-server-authorization-for-google-analytics-api-with-node-js/) documents right now. tried a lot more.

What currently I am stuck with is a Error

```
var analytics = google.analytics('v3');
                   ^
TypeError: google.analytics is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/server/services/data_resources/analytics/analyticsTest3.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Just can't understand what to do next

I have installed this module by

```
npm install googleapis --save
```

and nodejs version

```
node --version
v8.11.3
```

npm version is

```
npm --version
6.3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the google import to

```
var { google } = require('googleapis');
```

The curly brackets tell node to use destructuring, which will call the specific variable (including functions) that are exported from the required module.